# How to create a wallet from my own seed?

Tags: mnemonic-seed

I have my own diceware-based mnemonic seed which does not follow 25 word electrum-style rule.

For other coins I have used services like walletgenerator.net to generate wallet keys.

Is it possible to create deterministic wallet for Monero with own seed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you've created the equivalent of a 256 bit number by throwing dice.

First, you need to ensure your number is less than 2<sup>252</sup>+27742317777372353535851937790883648493 (which is the group size of the base point G).

This gives you your private spend key.

Then you need to compute a keccak(256) hash of the spend key, interpret the resulting 32 bytes as a number, and determine that number mod 2<sup>252</sup>+27742317777372353535851937790883648493.

This gives you your private view key.

If you want to generate your seed from your private spend key, you need to convert it to base 1626.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for the question. I did a little digging, and found a [link on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5aisaz/offline_wallet_generator_dice_d6_version/) to Jolly Mort's wonderful [off-line wallet using 98 dice rolls](https://jollymort.github.io/monero-wallet-generator/monero-wallet-generator-d6.html).

As suggested in the Reddit thread, ideally you'd want to use casino-grade dice. I am no expert into that, but e.g. search for "grade AAA dice". And obviously a disposable off-line computer (such as a Raspberry Pi where you physically destroy the SD-card after the operation).

Comment: This is an interesting approach. The number generated is up to about 6.0e75, vs the total possible private key range of up to 7.2e75. Therefore reducing the number is not required because it will never exceed the group size limit.